# HTML to CSS link not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

The link in my html file is not working. I'm not sure if it's something else, though. When I run the file, nothing appears on the screen. There are supposed to be five rectangles all different colors(you might be able to figure that out). This is probably a really easy fix, but I am a beginner and am in need of some quick help. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="play"></div>
        <div id="create"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="purple"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#play {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
}

#create {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    position: relative;
    height: 28%;
    width: 60%;
    top:2%;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
    height: 28%;
    width: 39%;
    position: relative;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 26%;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
    position: relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 90%;
}

#purple {
    background-color:purple;
    position:relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 160%;
}
```

Comment: may i know is your css file name stylesheet.css confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is shown because your body has **zero size**:

Just add this to your css:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77js54b4/1/)

```css
html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#play {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
}

#create {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    position: relative;
    height: 28%;
    width: 60%;
    top:2%;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
    height: 28%;
    width: 39%;
    position: relative;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 26%;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
    position: relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 90%;
}

#purple {
    background-color:purple;
    position:relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 160%;
}
```

```html
        
<div id="play"></div>
<div id="create"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="purple"></div>
```

Comment: Use a code snippet instead of JSFiddle please. External resources may go offline in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Set a height to your html and body element :

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your HTML and BODY element don't have a height. You set the elements to a percentage of zero, wich is always zero.

You need to set the height to a relative standard. Try to set your `HTML` and `BODY` height, then you can use the code you wanted.

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#play {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
}

#create {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    position: relative;
    height: 28%;
    width: 60%;
    top:2%;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
    height: 28%;
    width: 39%;
    position: relative;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 26%;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
    position: relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 90%;
}

#purple {
    background-color:purple;
    position:relative;
    height: 34%;
    width: 39%;
    left: 61%;
    bottom: 160%;
}
```

```html
        <div id="play"></div>
        <div id="create"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="purple"></div>
```

Comment: @DallasWhite You are welcome. If you accept any answer you get +2 rep ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would not have set the height of body and html.
Add the following in you css

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are giving height and width in percentage, you need to give height and width for body tag

For example:

```
body{
      height:100px; //either static or in percentage
      width:100px

    }
```

In css when you specify height or width in percentage, at least any one of its ancestor should have definite value for height/width

Comment: Updated ;) Thanks @Leothelion